Unexpected Behavior in Multithreaded Program Searching for Min/Max in Large Array
I’ve created a program for my studies that measures the execution time of a program that searches for the largest and smallest number in an array, depending on the number of threads used. To get results that can be easily compared, I need the largest array my computer can handle. Everything seems to work until my array is around 10k, then the largest and smallest numbers change and I can’t understand why. The problem seems to lie in the smallest number because it goes above 0.99
Here is my main class:
import java.util.Random;

public class Start {

    final static double[] ARRAY = new double[10000];
    final static int THREADS = 10;

    static double maxOut = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    static double minOut = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    final static int PLACEMENT = ARRAY.length/THREADS;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();

        long generatingStart=System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0 ;i < ARRAY.length; i++){
            ARRAY[i] = random.nextDouble();
            //System.out.println(ARRAY[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Czas generowania: " + ((System.nanoTime() - generatingStart) * 0.000001 )+"ms");

        Runnable [] watki = new Watek[THREADS];

        for(int i = 0; i< THREADS; i++){

            if(i == 0){
                watki[i] = new Watek(ARRAY, PLACEMENT, 0);
                //System.out.println("Watek "+i+" Zakres: "+0+" --> "+ PLACEMENT);
            }
            else if (i == THREADS - 1) {
                watki[i] = new Watek(ARRAY, ARRAY.length,i * PLACEMENT);
                //System.out.println("Watek "+i+" Zakres: "+i * PLACEMENT+" --> "+ ARRAY.length);
            }
            else {
                watki[i] = new Watek(ARRAY, (i+1) * PLACEMENT, i * PLACEMENT);
                //System.out.println("Watek "+i+" Zakres: "+i*PLACEMENT+" --> "+(i+1)*PLACEMENT);
            }
        }

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[THREADS];

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(watki[i]);
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        double duration = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) * 0.000001;

        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            //System.out.println("Thread " + i + " - Max: " + ((Watek) watki[i]).getMax() + " Min: " + ((Watek) watki[i]).getMin());
            if (( ((Watek) watki[i]).getMax()) > maxOut) {
                maxOut = ((Watek) watki[i]).getMax();
            }if (( ((Watek) watki[i]).getMin()) < minOut) {
                minOut = ((Watek) watki[i]).getMin();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maksymalna wartość w tablicy to: " + maxOut + ",natomiast minimalna to: "+minOut);
        System.out.println("Czas trawnia programu to: " + duration + "ms");
    }

}

And here is my thread code:
public class Watek implements Runnable {

    double[] arr;

    int maxBound;
    int minBound;
    double max;
    double min;


    public Watek(double[] arr, int maxBound, int minBound){
        this.arr = arr;
        this.maxBound = maxBound;
        this.minBound = minBound;
    }

    public double getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public double getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            this.max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            this.min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = minBound; i < maxBound; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > max) {
                    max = arr[i];
                }if (arr[i] < min) {
                    min = arr[i];
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

One of reruns show up this as output:
max = 0.9998978620408705, and min = 3.056044805038738E-5
Initially, I wrote this program for Integer values, and then I adjusted it for Double values. Everything worked as expected with Integer values. So, maybe I made a mistake when modifying the code.

I suspect the issue is that Double.MIN_VALUE does not mean what you think it means.  Read its documentation: it represents the smallest representable positive double value.

So, I checked it again and you’re right, but the problem doesn’t seem to lie there (if I’m thinking correctly) because Double.MIN_VALUE is used for the max value of the array and it works as expected.

is min = 3.056044805038738E-5 the wrong output? That number is not greater than 0.99! E-5 means multiply it by 10^-5 (ten to the power of -5) or 0.00001 - so min = 0.00003056044805038738 -- Wikipedia: Scientific Notation or StackOverflow: Long float-number output shows letters, Letters within integers. What are they?

Oh i didnt know this, im sorry for stupid question and thank you very much.
